# Is it possible to implicitly put a project dependency with Maven extension plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm developing a Maven plugin which introduces new packaging (extension). For all projects where this new packaging is applied I need to do two things:

- To customize lifecycle bindings, add some new bindings on my own plugin goals.
- To add certain dependency to the project

First objective I achieved by declaring my own `org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecycleMapping` in Plexus `components.xml` descriptor of my plugin. With second objective, however, I stumbled, and can't find any info on how it can be done (or even whether it is possible to be done by means of maven extensions mechanism).

Is there any way to implicitly put additional dependency to the project by means of Maven extension?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible.

Comment: It's sad. Thanks anyway